# Python application that adds an item to a List Widget, and edit and delete an item from it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have been struggling with this for quite sometime, to add male or female to either listbox1 or 2 is working like a charm, when I try to delete it does work but when I select one of the items in lets say listbox one and I go to listbox two it still keeps the selection I made active in listbox one thus when I click delete Iam deleting both the highlighted items in listbox1 and listbox2, now where iam struggling is the edit part iam not sure how to do this but let me explain I want to tell it that when listbox1 is selected edit only the selected item whether its in listbox1 or 2 but for some reading it only changes my row two of listbox2 when I try to make edit and it then also adds it to listbox1 here is my current script code:

```
import sys
from addlist import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.btnAddName, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addtolist)#calls the addtolist function
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.btnDelete, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.delete)#calls the delete function
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.btnEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.edit)#calls the edit function
        self.ui.rbMale.setChecked(1) #radio button rbMale checked by default when application loads

    #conditions whether name should be added to the Girls List or Boys List    
    def addtolist(self):
        if self.ui.rbMale.isChecked()==True:
            self.ui.lstBoys.addItem(self.ui.edtName.text())
            self.ui.edtName.setText('')
            self.ui.edtName.setFocus()
        elif self.ui.rbFemale.isChecked()==True:
            self.ui.lstGirls.addItem(self.ui.edtName.text())
            self.ui.edtName.setText('')
            self.ui.edtName.setFocus()

    #conditions whether name in Girls List or Boys List should be deleted
    def delete(self):
        self.ui.lstBoys.currentRow()
        self.ui.lstGirls.currentRow()        
        self.ui.lstBoys.takeItem(self.ui.lstBoys.currentRow())
        self.ui.lstGirls.takeItem(self.ui.lstGirls.currentRow())            

    def edit(self):
        #item1=self.ui.lstBoys.currentRow()
        #item2=self.ui.lstGirls.currentRow()

        if self.ui.lstBoys.currentRow():
            newtext, ok=QInputDialog.getText(self, "Enter new Name", "Enter new Name")
            if ok and (len(newtext)!=0):            
                self.ui.lstBoys.takeItem(self.ui.lstBoys.currentRow())
                self.ui.lstBoys.insertItem(self.ui.lstBoys.currentRow(), QListWidgetItem(newtext))
        else:
            newtext1, oke=QInputDialog.getText(self, "Enter new Name", "Enter new Name")
            if oke and (len(newtext1)!=0):            
                self.ui.lstGirls.takeItem(self.ui.lstGirls.currentRow())
                self.ui.lstGirls.insertItem(self.ui.lstGirls.currentRow(), QListWidgetItem(newtext1)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Assistance will be much appreciated.
Thank you

As requested please see below:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

 # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'addlist.ui'
 #
 # Created: Mon Aug  7 09:31:01 2017
 #      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.9.6
 #
 # WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

 from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

 try:
     _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
 except AttributeError:
     def _fromUtf8(s):
          return s

 try:
     _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
     def _translate(context, text, disambig):
         return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
 except AttributeError:
     def _translate(context, text, disambig):
         return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

 class Ui_Dialog(object):
     def setupUi(self, Dialog):
         Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
         Dialog.resize(678, 420)
         self.btnAddName = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
         self.btnAddName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 310, 93, 51))
         self.btnAddName.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnAddName"))
         self.btnDelete = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
         self.btnDelete.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 90, 93, 28))
         self.btnDelete.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnDelete"))
         self.btnEdit = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
         self.btnEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 140, 93, 28))
         self.btnEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnEdit"))
         self.gpbGirls = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
         self.gpbGirls.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 50, 171, 221))
         self.gpbGirls.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gpbGirls"))
         self.lstGirls = QtGui.QListWidget(self.gpbGirls)
         self.lstGirls.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 151, 191))
         self.lstGirls.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lstGirls"))
         self.gpbBoys = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
         self.gpbBoys.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 50, 171, 221))
         self.gpbBoys.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gpbBoys"))
         self.lstBoys = QtGui.QListWidget(self.gpbBoys)
         self.lstBoys.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 151, 192))
         self.lstBoys.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lstBoys"))
         self.gpbGender = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
         self.gpbGender.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 299, 211, 61))
         self.gpbGender.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gpbGender"))
         self.rbMale = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gpbGender)
         self.rbMale.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 71, 20))
         self.rbMale.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("rbMale"))
         self.rbFemale = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gpbGender)
         self.rbFemale.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 81, 20))
         self.rbFemale.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("rbFemale"))
         self.gpbName = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
         self.gpbName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 300, 171, 61))
         self.gpbName.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gpbName"))
         self.edtName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.gpbName)
         self.edtName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(2, 20, 161, 41))
         self.edtName.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("edtName"))

         self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

     def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
         Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
         self.btnAddName.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Add Name", None))
         self.btnDelete.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Delete", None))
         self.btnEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Edit", None))
         self.gpbGirls.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Girl\'s Names", None))
         self.gpbBoys.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Boy\'s Names", None))
         self.gpbGender.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Gender", None))
         self.rbMale.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Male", None))
         self.rbFemale.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Female", None))
         self.gpbName.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Enter name:", None))
```

Comment: Would you mind please including the `addlist` module.

Comment: Please provide an mvce, for it is necessary that you show the code of the class Ui_Dialog.

Comment: Please see updated and added above